# Third party software COM library free/open usage?

Tags: .net, com, reference, shared-libraries, dcom

On Windows, can I freely make usage of a COM library that has been registered by a commercial application (software)?  Is the company allowed to remove completely its COM library or some functions of the COM library in a future release? 
Are there some Microsoft legal data about this topic and where could I find them?

Comment: How you re-use a piece of software really depends on the software vendor. You must contact the vendor for more information, Microsoft has nothing to do with this (it only cares about its own components).

Answer (score 1):

COM is a technology for code reuse and versioning and interfacing with third party code, it has nothing to do with granting rights to use pieces of software. Think of it this way - if there's a .NET assembly you can easily interface with it (there's enough metadata inside), but unless the author allows that it would be illegal.

You have to carefully read the software piece end user license agreement to find whether your usecase is allowed.